# initialise a SQL Table of oneToOne Relation

Tags: hibernate

Using Hibernate, I have a class `Company` and `Address` with a `OneToOne` relation.

I am using Hibernate to populate the table (so it's via the code), I have no problem retrieving a `Company` and it's `Address`

But if I empty the table `Company` and `Address` and then add an entry (insert into sql) into the `Company` table with an id = 1 and add an entry into the address table with an id = 1, when trying to get the `Person`, I have the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/frmk] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1, for class: com.snj.frmk.core.orga.model.Address] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1, for class: com.snj.frmk.core.orga.model.Address
```

Both classes `Address` and `Company` inherit from `Person` which itself inherits from another object.
I've provided some incomplete sample code below.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class SnjObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3051191273679675478L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Id
    public Long id;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Person extends SnjObject  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1782694326465928216L;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="person", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address adr1;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SNJ_COMPANY")
public class Company extends Person{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5591910647468433471L;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SNJ_ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "person"))
    private Long id;
}
```

I've also included the SQL to insert the value into the `Company` and `Address` table:
`INSERT INTO snj_company (ID,CODE_REFERENCE,NAME,SIZE,OFFICE_PHONE,FAX,MOBILE_PHONE,EMAIL,creatorId) VALUES (1,'FR00101','TEST',0,'0948878398', '', '', '' ,1);`

`INSERT into snj_address (ID,ADR_NUM,ADR_STREET,ADR_POSTALCODE,ADR_CITY,ADR_COUNTRY) values (1,'0', '73 STREET', '', 'CITY', '');`

Comment: could you post the code that is clearing the table and inserting the new record please? also what version of Hibernate are you using? I think you are using Hibernate 4 with annotation based transaction configuration but I'd like that confirmed please.

Comment: I am indeed using Hibernate : 4.2.2.Final. About clearing the table, no code. I opened Mysql Workbench, select with the mouse all the row, click on delete. The workbench execute a delete from <table> where .... for every single selected row

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to generate your ID column and you don't have any requirement that specifies otherwise, you should use a database Sequence generator on each ID field. If you are using hibernate in `create-drop` mode then you will have no problems as Hibernate will create the sequence and automatically use it to populate your ID field when you insert a new record. I'll give you an example of what this would look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SNJ_ADDRESS")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")        
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "contactSequence") //specifies what generator you want
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "contactSequence", sequenceName = "CONTACT_SEQ") 
    /*Specifies that you want to use a database Sequence as your generator and the 
    name of that sequence. If it doesn't exist, Hibernate will create it.*/
    private Long ID.
```

If you have another ID field that you want to set using a sequence, just give a different `sequenceName` and Hibernate will create you a new Sequence.
Can you post the code that you are using to clear the tables and then do the insert? Also which version of Hibernate are you using? I'm going to assume that you are using Hibernate 4 with annotation based transaction configuration.

What some people don't realise (and it isn't really spelled out in the documentation if you don't read it carefully) is that Hibernate won't commit any changes to the database until your transaction ends and the session is closed.

The problem you described above occurs because either the session isn't being committed after the delete (most likely scenario) so that when you try to save another address it is detecting a primary key conflict and refusing to save. Otherwise it is saving the data, and when you are trying to retrieve your `Person`, Hibernate is finding two rows that have the same ID and stopping because it doesn't know which one you want.

TL;DR Don't directly manipulate or set your ID's, let Hibernate generate them from database Sequences and this issue will go away.

Comment: I am using Hibernate : 4.2.2.Final. About clearing the table, no code, it's done manually: I opened Mysql Workbench, select with the mouse all the row, click on delete. The workbench executes a delete sql statement : delete from <table> where .... for every single selected row. About : " DR Don't directly manipulate or set your ID's, let Hibernate generate them from database Sequences and this issue will go away", to initiate my database when deploying my application, does it means I have to insert data via the code and not via SQL statements ?

Comment: There is an XML config option to run an SQL script when initialising your database. The config is available pretty much everywhere. Its always best to populate your database from an SQL script run when the database starts up. That way you know what is inside the database when you start. Just make sure you are creating the sequences using the SQL scripts and using them to set the ID's